# QGIS Snow Cover extent extract

Tags: qgis, polygon, extract

I have a year worth of daily snow cover data in tif files.
I want to merge them all into one (stack) and select a polygon from which I want to extract snow cover extent as in sqare miles and as % of total area.

I want to create time series of all the daily files for a selected square location area.

[image]

Comment: What's that map image got to do with it? Are all your TIF files properly registered in the same coordinates and the same bounds? Would it be easier to extract the polygon region first because that would reduce huge tif files to small ones first?

Comment: This image shows the data classes (5) I want to extract only the red cells from the EuraSia. How do I extract values in a selected polygon??

Comment: I'd just add that this kind of process is way easier in R with the raster package. Is this NSIDC 25km, AMSR-E 6.25km in the native polar stereographic on the north pole - or something else? It's well worth learning to use R (and raster) for this. If I see a workflow described in QGIS that's reasonably comparable, I'll eat my digital hat.

Comment: yes NSIDC but 4 or 1km.  I am happy to use R as well. will probably make a new question and delete that.